# Can't broadcast from isolated scope in directive—negative implications of setting directive scope to false?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

I have a situation where I would like to `$broadcast` from within a directive's linking function—where that directive has an isolated scope. Unfortunately, since directive `scope` is not prototypically inherited from the parent `$scope` broadcasting from inside an isolated scope is impossible, — [reference.](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2725-how-scope-broadcast-interacts-with-isolate-scopes-in-angularjs.htm)

I know that using `scope: false` on my directive will cause the directive to use the scope of it's parent, potentially crowding the parent scope, and leading to possible naming collisions, etc—making the directive less reliable for reusability.

So, maybe I can be careful about crowding the parent scope. Are there other reasons why I may not want to use `scope: false` on a directive that is intended to be reused?—Is it simply a preferences and 'tidiness' thing or are there actual other negative implications?

As far as I know, there are no alternatives to getting the functionality that is achieved from broadcasting from inside a directive's linking function—other than maybe having the directive change a service, (which is impossible in my situation because of the parent scope hierarchy)—so as far as I can tell, using `$broadcast` is the only way. Any direction is appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: To be clear, my intention is to broadcast from inside the isolated scope, downwards to the parent scope's children, i.e.

JS

```
.controller('parent', function ($scope) {
  $scope.parent = 'parentProperty';
})
.directive('isolate', function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    template: '<div ng-click="click()">Click</div>',
    link: function (scope) {
      scope.click = function () {
        console.log('clicked,but no broadcast');
      scope.$broadcast('event', 'string');
      }
    }
    };
})
.directive('child', function () {
  return {
  link: function(scope) {
    scope.$on('event', function (e, event) {
      console.log(event);
    });
  }
};
});
```

HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="parent">
    <div isolate>Click me to broadcast
      </div>
      <div child>
        </div>
  </body>
```

PLNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/wKDOP4UpdgDFrHvzY0UN?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've misinterpreted the article you link to. You *can* broadcast events to isolate scopes. It is even stated that in the post you reference:

> As you can see, the isolate scope was able to listen for events being broadcast down through the scope hierarchy; however, it was not able to see the related scope value, "pingCount" in its parent scope.

The trick is to remember that in AngularJS `$broadcast` sends events *down* the parent/child scope hierarchy (including isolate scopes).You can use `$emit` to send events *up* the hierarchy.

It sounds like you want to use `$emit` inside your directive's link function, that way the event will go to the parent scopes. [Explanation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) from the docs.

**EDIT**

Ok, here's a simple approach using two events. The directive first uses `$emit()` to send an event to the parent scope. The parent scope uses `$on()` to wait for this event. When it occurs, it uses `$broadcast()` to send another event down to all child scopes.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z08lPfobXYVL8gfMBTA8?p=preview)

This is primitive and will likely breakdown. Instead you might take a look at using the `require` property of directives and have a controller with an API that the child directives use to communicate.

Comment: My point is that if you want the parent scope to "hear" the event you need to use `$emit()` rather than `$broadcast()`.

Comment: Gotcha. So does the isolate scope act as a child to the parent scope and therefore it can only ```$emit``` upwards? — i.e it would never be able to ```$broadcast``` down to the parent scope's children? In which case, scope must be set to ```false``` — if you want to ```$broadcast```.

Comment: `$broadcast` and `$emit` do the the same thing: they dispatch your event. For performance reasons (?) you only dispatch the events UP to parent scopes (using $emit) or DOWN to child scopes (using $broadcast). Since you want to send something from the isolate scope to it's parent scope, you need to use $emit.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear. I want to ```$broadcast``` to the parent's children, from the isolate scope.—btw, thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry. It is still unclear to me how to ```$brodcast``` from an isolated scope. I have made a plnkr to better demonstrate the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/wKDOP4UpdgDFrHvzY0UN?p=preview

Comment: Ok I modified your plunker and described it above.